# Backed up toilet, I can't remove the water from the bowl

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain

My toilet is backed up and I have been plunging for hours now. As I was plunging it started overflowing with water. So, I used my shop vac to take some of the water out but as much as I was draining, it was filling back up.

I turned the water to the toilet off, but it is still filling right back up to the top of the bowl. It is only affecting this toilet and all the other drains are working fine.

Any clue why it is filling back up or any fixes to this problem?

Comment: If you take the toilet tank lid off, are any of the valves in there flowing water?  Even a drip?    You *really* ought to narrow down whether this is fresh water from toilet valves, or sewage backing up from the drain.

Comment: To ensure your toilet valve is turned off - turn it off and disconnect the water line at the underside of the tank. You can lay the water line into a bucket in case it is still flowing a little. After you are sure you do not have any fresh water feeding the tank you can plunge it., if it still fills back up, clear the clog with a snake down the toilet drain pipe or call a plumber that has a camera (any nearby trees - roots can grow into the drain pipes), also check your roof vents to make sure you are clear - animals can crawl down some and get stuck in the drain.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. Either you didn't get the toilet valve shut off completely.
2. Or, the water from the tank is filling the bowl and it will stop once that is empty.
3. If this is a basement toilet, it is also possible the main line is clogged and all drain water is backing up into the toilet. But you said all the other drains are fine. It may be they are just draining into the basement toilet.

Go back and re-check the toilet valve to make sure it is shut off completely. If this fails to stop the water shut off the main valve for the whole house while you correct the problem.

Plungers don't work on serious clogs you may need to buy or rent a drain snake.

If all else fails, call a drain cleaning service. They have heavy duty equipment for these emergencies.

Good luck!